# WooCommerce sort product list by attribute

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, attributes

I am novice to WordPress and WooCommerce.

I am using `WordPress 5.0.2` with `WooCommerce 3.5.2`.

I am getting product list using following code:

```
<?php 

$per_make = null; 
if ($_POST){
    if (isset($_POST["make"])){
        $per_make = $_POST["make"];
        setcookie('c-per_make', $_POST["make"], time() + (86400 * 30));
    }
    else {
        setcookie('c-per_make', "", time() + (86400 * 30));
    }
}
else {
    if ($_COOKIE['c-per_make']){
        $per_make = $_COOKIE['c-per_make'];
    }
}

$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;                       
$product_query_arr = array(
        'post_type'      => array('product'),
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'tax_query'      => array()
);

$taxonomy_arr[]  = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
    'field'         => 'slug', 
    'terms'         => 'a-category-slug',
    'operator'      => 'IN'
);

if (isset($per_make) && !empty($per_make)){
    $make = get_term_by('slug', $per_make, 'product_cat');
    $taxonomy_arr[]=array(
            'taxonomy'        => 'pa_make',
            'field'           => 'name',
            'terms'           =>  array($make->name),
            'operator'        => 'IN',
        );

}

$product_query_arr['tax_query'] = $taxonomy_arr; 
$products = new WP_Query($product_query_arr); 

?>
```

Now, I want to `sort` the results in `ascending` order by another attribute named `pa_engine` that contains string value, but I am not sure how to make it. 
I tried adding it in `$taxonomy_arr[]` as well as `order_by` and `order` key in `$product_query_arr` but seems not working.

Can any one let me know how to implement it? Or am I following some wrong path to implement it?

Comment: Any WooCommerce / Wordpress experts here?